# Error installing Spacy ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Tags: windows, installation, spacy

I'm trying to install Spacy on a Windows machine of 32 bits. I have python 3.8.

I get this error when I try to install Spacy (output is too long, I'll insert a fragment)

```html
(base) C:\Users\User>pip install spacy --no-cache-dir
Collecting spacy
  Downloading spacy-2.3.2.tar.gz (5.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.9 MB 3.3 MB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\user\anaconda3\python.exe' 'c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zhupmafd\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.25' 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=3.0.2,<3.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' thinc==7.4.1
       cwd: None
  Complete output (430 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-50.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (784 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
  Collecting cython>=0.25
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (1.6 MB)
  Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
    Using cached cymem-2.0.3.tar.gz (51 kB)
  Collecting preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2
    Using cached preshed-3.0.2.tar.gz (167 kB)
  Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
    Using cached murmurhash-1.0.2.tar.gz (35 kB)
  Collecting thinc==7.4.1
    Using cached thinc-7.4.1.tar.gz (1.3 MB)
  Collecting blis<0.5.0,>=0.4.0
    Using cached blis-0.4.1.tar.gz (1.8 MB)
  Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.0.9
    Using cached wasabi-0.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
  Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6
    Using cached srsly-1.0.2.tar.gz (192 kB)
  Collecting catalogue<1.1.0,>=0.0.7
    Using cached catalogue-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.7 kB)
  Collecting numpy>=1.7.0
    Using cached numpy-1.19.1-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (10.9 MB)
  Collecting plac<1.2.0,>=0.9.6
    Using cached plac-1.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
  Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0
    Using cached tqdm-4.48.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (68 kB)
  Building wheels for collected packages: cymem, preshed, murmurhash, thinc, blis, srsly
    Building wheel for cymem (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for cymem (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\user\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4jggcsja\\cymem\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4jggcsja\\cymem\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-chusorxt'
         cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4jggcsja\cymem\
```

I have tried:

- `pip install spacy`
- `conda install -c conda-forge spacy`
- `pip install spacy --no-cache-dir`

Nothing works! What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Spacy has dropped support for 32 bit and so you'll need to use 64 bit Python.